# Can't install npm existing package. Error code E404

Tags: npm

I am trying to install hyperledger composer. Following the documentation the CLI is installed with:

```
sudo npm install -g composer-cli
```

*Note: I am using sudo since I haven't fixed the folder permissions.*

Gives:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: protobufjs@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-05-30T01_12_34_393Z-debug.log
```

Trying with

```
sudo npm install -g protobufjs
```

Gives same error. Logs here:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'i', '-g', 'protobufjs' ]
2 info using npm@6.1.0
3 info using node@v10.2.1
4 verbose npm-session bdb39df4dc363070
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/protobufjs 394ms
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for protobufjs@latest 404 Not Found: protobufjs@latest
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 510ms
11 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: protobufjs@latest
11 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/fetch.js:42:19)
11 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
11 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
11 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:696:18)
11 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:667:5)
11 verbose stack     at processImmediate (timers.js:649:5)
12 verbose cwd /home/vanclief
13 verbose Linux 4.14.13-1-ARCH
14 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "-g" "protobufjs"
15 verbose node v10.2.1
16 verbose npm  v6.1.0
17 error code E404
18 error 404 Not Found: protobufjs@latest
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I checked on my browser and I can see the package:

```
https://registry.npmjs.org/protobufjs
```

I tried using a npm registry mirror and even yarn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a npm issue. Waiting until a fix.

https://status.npmjs.org/
https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js/issues/1056